# ValueError: No Shapely geometry can be created from null value

Tags: python, shapely

I get this error while using `cascaded_union` (I have also tried `unary_union` which produces the same error):

```
ValueError: No Shapely geometry can be created from null value
```

I have validated that my polygons are valid.  Initially `polyB` isn't valid, but it is converted to a valid polygon using `buffer(0)`.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?  Here's my code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

def combineBorders(a, b):
    polyA = Polygon(a)
    polyB = Polygon(b)
    pols = [polyA, polyB]

    for p in pols:
        if p.is_valid == False:
            p = p.buffer(0)
        print(p.is_valid)
```

```
True
True
```

```
    newShape = cascaded_union(pols) # THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR KEEPS SHOWING UP
    return newShape
```

[Here is a link](http://pythonfiddle.com/shapely-data) to the values for polyA, polyB and pols (after they are confirmed to be valid).  I have the following versions installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 server:

- python-shapely 1.3.0
- libgeos 3.4.2
- python 2.7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem in the question is that the buffered polygon was not put back in the list `pols`, so the invalid geometry was passed to `cascaded_union`

You could make this much simpler and versatile with the following, which can take any number of polygon geometries (not just two).

```
def combineBorders(*geoms):
    return cascaded_union([
        geom if geom.is_valid else geom.buffer(0) for geom in geoms
    ])

polyC = combineBorders(polyA, polyB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem.  Not sure why this matters (I've seen examples showing it both ways), but it works after putting the polygons directly into cascaded_union like so: `newShape = cascaded_union([polyA, polyB])`.  Here is the fully revised code that works:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

def combineBorders(a, b):
    polyA = Polygon(a)
    polyB = Polygon(b)
    polyBufA = polyA.buffer(0)
    polyBufB = polyB.buffer(0)
    newShape = cascaded_union([polyBufA, polyBufB])
    return newShape
```

This also works with `unary_union`